# Angular2/4 Dynamic Checkbox/Radio Styling

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an Angular 2/4 application where a user can set his own style. This means he can set a color which is then used for links, buttons etc. This is done by directives e.g. like that:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '.btn-primary'
})

export class ColorDirective {
    @HostBinding('style.color') color: string;

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
        this.store.select('config', 'config').subscribe((config: Config) => {
            this.color = config.color;
        });
    }
}
```

Now we'd also like to style the checkboxes and radio buttons like that. They are currently styled using `:before` and `:checked` selectors. Angular cannot select on pseudoelements. Thus the approach above is not possible. Any ideas how to achieve this outcome?

Comment: Can you show us example of style on `:before` pseudoelement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280118/change-style-of-pseudo-elements-in-angular2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549294/angular-2-setting-pseudo-element-css

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293053/can-i-use-angularjs-directives-to-apply-a-style-to-a-pseudo-element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498920/how-to-change-style-for-before-after-in-angular

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352514/how-to-set-the-css-of-the-libefore-with-ng-style

Comment: The styling is something like: `.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before { color: #343434; }`

Comment: @StephenThomas I can't find a solution in any of the link on how to set the color dynamically at runtime. E.g. I cannot add classes, because I don't know the color beforehand.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables would be a nice solution but still experimental.

Comment: "I can't find a solution..." That's my point! A solution doesn't exist. A question that's been asked that many times and has no solution should be your first clue.